# Цвет заднего фона и цвет кода в Visual C# 2010

Tags: ide, visual-studio

Всем привет, скажите, как можно сделать так же, как на картинке. Такая красота, аж кодить становится намного приятнее.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Studio Theme Generator](http://www.frickinsweet.com/tools/Theme.mvc.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения цвета самой студии использую плагин [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378) 
Для изменения цвета редактора кода использовал тему с [Visual Studio color](http://studiostyl.es/), там же найдешь мануалы по установке и изменению